# Firebase return retrieved value from addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to **Firebase** and what I have learned from the documentation of **Firebase** is, that if you want to retrieve a data just once you are going to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

My problem is to integrate that in my code. 
I have such kind of data structure:

[image]

Now I want to add a new object under **16032017**. To do that I have to do the following steps:

1. First I have to look if **16032017** exists or not
2. I have to look how many children it has (in this example 3)
3. After getting the amount if children, I will create a new subnode with key 3   and insert my data-value pair, which is an object like this:

   ```
   public class StimmungAbfrage {
       public Integer Angespannt ;
       public Integer Motiviert;
   }
   ```

With other databases, it would be pretty easy. I would implement it exactly in the order I have described. First reading the data and returning the value, then using the value to insert the new data. But I cannot find the way to do that with **Firebase**. Because in **Firebase** first I have to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to read the amount of subnodes. I have written the code like this:

```
URL url = new URL(DAL_Utilities.DatabaseURL  +  "players/" + user.getName() + "/Stimmungsabfrage/" + stimmungAbfrage.Date + "/");
Firebase root = new Firebase(url.toString());
root.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        long counter = 1;
        counter = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.d("DAL_User.GetLTSabfrage",firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

But the problem is that I cannot get the value of `counter` back, because it is `void`. So there is no way to return the data to use it in another function for the Insert process. 
Then I tried to do the reading and inserting transaction in the `onDataChange`. But this is also not possible, because I was not able to find a way to pass the data to this function, that I want to insert in the database. Also the function is not able to get access to the data of the main class where `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is implemented, unless I make all the variable global, which is not the right way to do.
So how can I implement this simple read and write process with **Firebase**?

Comment: You don't have to look to see if the parent node exists or not. Firebase is schemaless. Also, [avoid sequential, numeric ids](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)--use the push ids as described in the [guide on working with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#update_specific_fields) if you don't have a unique identifier to use as the key. You don't need any of this, follow the guide and best practices and it'll be far simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ref.child("16032017").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                   for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {


                       StimmungAbfrage stim = postSnapshot.getValue(StimmungAbfrage.class);


                       String string = " Angespannt: "+stim.get Angespannt()+"\nMotiviert: "+stim.getMotiviert();


                       textView.setText(string);
                   }
                }});
```